# Socket programming between different networks

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, hole-punching

I'm developing a client-server program in c++ to transfer data from one computer to another.

Everything works fine but now I was asked to make it work on computers on different networks. I have searched everywhere but can't find a reliable solution.

I've seen the TCP hole punching solution but can't seem to find anywhere how to do it in c++.

I want it to work like teamviewer but without an intermediary server.
Connect my client (on one computer) to the server (on another computer in a different network) all programmatically.

```
#include "../include/ip_tunnel_ms_windows_20180815.h" 
#include "../include/message_processor_common_20190410.h"


SOCKET clientSocket;
int n = 0;
void IPTunnel::initialize(void)
{

    if (inputSignals.empty()) {
        printf("server%d\n", n++);
        if (!server()) {
            printf("Error opening server\n");
            ::exit(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("client%d\n", n++);
        if (!client()) {
            printf("Error opening client\n");
            ::exit(1);
        }
    }
}


bool IPTunnel::runBlock(void)
{
    .....
    (transmit data)
    .....
    return true;
}

void IPTunnel::terminate(void) {
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

bool IPTunnel::server() {
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't Initialize winsock! Quitting" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = ntohs(tcpPort);
    //inet_pton(AF_INET, (PCSTR)remoteMachineIpAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr.s_addr); // hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ipAddressServer.c_str());
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    if (::bind(listening, (sockaddr*)& hint, sizeof(hint)) < 0) {
        printf("\n ERROR on binding");
        return false;
    }

    if (listen(listening, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
        printf("\n ERROR on binding");
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)& client, &clientSize);

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)& client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " <<
            ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }
    return true;
}

bool IPTunnel::client() {

    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return false;
    }

    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(tcpPort);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, remoteMachineIpAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    int connResult = -2;
    while (connResult != 0 || numberOfTrials == 0) {
        connResult = connect(clientSocket, (sockaddr*)& hint, sizeof(hint));
        if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            cerr << "Waiting " << timeIntervalSeconds << " seconds." << endl;
        }

        Sleep(timeIntervalSeconds * 1000);
        ;
        if (--numberOfTrials == 0) {
            cerr << "Reached maximum number of attempts." << endl;
            ::exit(1);
        }
    }
    cout << "Connected!\n";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your program shouldn't need to change. Just make the IP addresses configurable. It is the network that needs configuring to make one network visible to another.

Comment: I want it to work like a software life teamviewer. Without configuring anything else

Comment: Eliminating the requirement to configure firewalls/NATs is the primary reason software like teamviewer uses an intermediary server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [definition of hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) includes:

> Both clients initiate a connection to an unrestricted server

You say:

> I want it to work like teamviewer but without an intermediary server

That's not possible in general.

Comment: But I know the public IP of the server, so why would I need an intermediary? All that unrestricted server does, is to give this information to the other..

Comment: @Borbat Because firewalls are often configured to block unsolicited inbound connections.  Or the public IP address may be shared with other systems behind a NAT.  In both those common cases the system is able to make an outbound connection no problem, but an inbound connection would require network configuration.  That's why software often uses an intermediary server that both endpoints can make an outbound connection to.

Comment: @MilesBudnek ok, I'm getting what you're saying. So should i have a server on another computer just receiving connections from the 2 peers?

Comment: @Borbat: Yes, you can implement hole punching or STUN or similar techniques.  Perhaps the central server can be based on a preexisting open source project.

Comment: There are ways to make that work, sort of. An unrestricted server is needed to coordinate things, but it's possible to get two things behind a NAT to connect directly to each other with a technique called 'Simultaneous SYN Exchange'. But, the NATs involved have to work in a particular way for it to work.

Comment: @Omnifarious: To be clear, that's totally impractical for OP, but a fun thing to think about.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I wrote this about it in 2000 - http://www.omnifarious.org/~hopper/technical/tcp_splicing.html

Comment: @Omnifarious: Amazing, thanks for the detailed link.